# How to iterate over a function

Tags: python-3.x, loops, iteration

So here is my code:

```
def background(arr2,arr3):

    for i in arr3:
        for j in arr2:
            i = 0
            j = 0
            left_points = x<(arr3[i])
            right_points = x>(arr2[j])
            indices = left_points | right_points
            i = i + 1
            j = j + 1            
            return indices

    backgroundy = background(arr2,arr3)
```

*****Code ends here*****

```
arr2 is array([38.6, 44.4, 63.3, 75.3, 79.1, 93.9])
arr3 is array([33.6, 39.4, 58.3, 70.3, 74.1, 88.9])
```

I am trying to iterate over each of the points in the arrays to get a bool array where the values between arr2 and arr3 and false. Currently this code can do it for the first set of values (33.6 and 38.6), but I cant seem to get it to iterate across all the values. 
I feel like this is quite an easy thing to do but i'v been trying for hours and i cant get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: return Ends the function. It dies - only thing coming out is its return value. either iterate inside the function and collect your results in a list that you return or iterate outside the values and call the function to get the result of one evaluation.

Comment: beside that: [mre] your code is incomplete and does not run. probably due to misindentation - also infinite loop as is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a for-loop with an index to iterate over both arrays:

```
arr4 = []
for i in range(len(arr2)):
     left_points = x<(arr3[i])
     right_points = x>(arr2[i])
     arr4.append(left_points | right_points)
```

Comment: I get 'IndexError: list assignment index out of range'

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up dicts with lists.